# Deny specific mobile app access to Parse.com app

Tags: parse-platform, soa

Background:
I’ve been tasked to move the organization that I currently work for, towards SOA (Service Oriented Architecture). I’ve been exploring API management tools such as Mashery, Apigee, etc. Due to extremely limited resources and funding, I’ve considered building this data layer on the Parse.com platform (at least for a POC), due to my previous experience with Parse. However, I’m unable find a way to reconcile a few of the limitations that would come along with using Parse.com as an API management tool.

Scenario:
I have multiple, separate clients (iOS app A, iOS app B, iOS app C, etc.) which interface with one Parse application for purposes of having all Users and other data shared between mobile apps. We decide that we don’t want app B to interface with our Parse.com app.

Question:
Is there a way to deny access to one of these specific applications (e.g., app B), while still providing access to the others, without resubmitting all of the apps in the suite with updated keys?

Comment: How hard would it be to add this feature to all of your current apps? Are you looking for a long-term way to manage this, or a short-term "kick out iOS App B"?

Comment: Ideally, we'd like a long-term way to handle this. We have several mobile applications, and want to enable third parties to leverage our data also, possibly generating revenue from our shared content.

Comment: Then you could add a class in Parse called, say, "Permissions". In it, you could list all of the, say, AppIds that have access to the Parse app. At launch of each iOS app, you could run a `PFQuery` that would check whether the app's AppId is listed in the `Permissions` table. If not, don't let the app run (or maybe just don't let the iOS app access the Parse app). This technique is likely to not get approval from Apple, but it sounds like you might be doing Enterprise app development.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work. How would I force a 3rd party mobile app to check this Permissions class? I believe I need some type of server-side solution to perform this. .. We have enterprise and App Store apps, and Android apps too.

Comment: Well, the apps have to be designed to interface with your Parse app, which (I would expect) means that you have coded them with your Parse app's App ID and Key. Basically, you have to have control over the app for it to be able to talk to Parse. If you don't have that, Parse isn't going to work. I think I misunderstood that all of the apps interfacing with Parse were under your control. Or am I still missing something? How are you allowing a 3rd party mobile app to access your Parse app now?

Comment: I envision using a single Parse app as a virtualization layer, supporting any app (owned and 3rd party). Mimicking the functionality of many API management tools, I'd distribute the Client Key and App Key to 3rd parties to build upon the API (Parse app).

Comment: I don't think Parse is the right tool for that job. Theoretically, you could use the Parse Installation class to manage this, but you'd still have to build other tables/classes that referenced what bundle identifiers were allowed, etc. Even then, I can't think of a way to shut down communications from the Parse side; the only way I can think of is to do it from the app's side.

Comment: I'm also starting to come to this conclusion. I'll give it bit more thought, and continue to monitor incoming comments. Thanks for your input.